# Changing button font-size also changes width on ios

Tags: html, ios, css

When I change font-size to 18pt then button width also changes. This happens only on iphone and works fine on android or windows.

I have tried: -webkit-appearance: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; font-size-adjust: none; width with !important, mixing them and using asp:button instead. Nothing helps.

```css
.mainbtn {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18pt;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 39px !important;
    height: 39px;
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid transparent !important;
    table-layout: fixed;
    font-size-adjust: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

    .mainbtn.green {
        border: 2px solid lightgreen !important;
    }
```

```html
<button ID="Button5" runat="server" class="mainbtn green" />
```

[image: screen]
This is how it should looks.

[image: screen]
This is how it looks on iphone. (wider)

You can check it out by yourself on http://sudoku.somee.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-webkit-text-size-adjust: unset;` for ios devices. And you're done!

```css
.mainbtn {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 39px !important;
    height: 39px;
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid transparent !important;
    table-layout: fixed;
    font-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: unset;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

    .mainbtn.green {
        border: 2px solid lightgreen !important;
    }
```

```html
<button ID="Button5" runat="server" class="mainbtn green" >GO</button>
```

Comment: That works fine when I change 18pt to 18px. However 18 px smaller than 18 pt and when I change font-size to 25px then same story happens =(

Comment: That was because of missing -webkit-text-size-adjust: 0%;.

Comment: No issues with width after that change and that's great! However, when I add text (by asp:button text="1" or just <button>1</button>) then text doesn't show up on iphone at all =(

Comment: With "unset" it changes width as before. I even tried to use em as in your example (1,8em). Same result =(

Comment: It is because the width of box is smaller than text. You must either decrease font-size or increase box size. Hope this is the fact that you must adjust in either way. It is not possible to put 1000 kg elephant in a 150 kg refrigerator.